# How to know if a rar file is password protected through file signature using Java?

Tags: java, rar

Is there a way to check if a RAR file is password protected by looking at its file signature or any other methods in Java?

I already know the RAR file signature is `52 61 72 21 1A 07 00`, but how can I tell if the file is protected through the file signature? Or can you suggest a way to detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the RAR file format spec:

http://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm#enchead

It looks like you would need to step through the headers -- using the header size and header type fields to guide you -- until you either reach the "end of data" header or an "archive encryption" header.

This means traversing most of the file. You could make this perform reasonably well for a file on disk by using `MemoryMapReader` to avoid chewing through the bytes you're not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a third-party library. [Junrar](https://github.com/junrar/junrar/) is a popular one.

Using Junrar you could write something like:

```
public boolean isArchiveEncrypted(String pathToFile)
{
    try
    {
        Archive arch = new Archive(new File(pathToFile));
        return arch.isEncrypted();
    }
    catch (RarException e)
    {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

*(I have not tested the above code)*